# Warning: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion when using NS_ENUM types

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I am using an enum, something like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyURLType) {
    MyURLType1,
    MyURLType2,
    MyURLType3
};
```

The problem appears when I try to compare or identify the type:

```
if (type == MyURLType2)
```

I am getting a `"Incompatible integer to pointer conversion"` warning in the case of `MyUrlType2` and `MyUrlType3` (not in the case of `MyURLType1`). Am I doing anything wrong in the declaration? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is __type__ here? integer? or variable of `MyURLType`?

Comment: Is a variable of MyURLType

Comment: show me the declaration of `type` you may use * like MyURLType *type

Comment: Yes, I am using MyURLType *type = MyURLTypeX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your comment

> Yes, I am using MyURLType *type = MyURLTypeX

Then `type` is not of type `MyURLType`, it is of type `pointer to MyURLType`.

```
if (type == MyURLType2)
```

Here you are comparing a pointer type (`type`) to an integer type (`MyURLType`). If the integer type is `0` it doesn't generate a warning, because it could be a check for `NULL`.

You either need to declare `type` as a simple `MyURLType` (`MyURLType type =…`) or dereference `type` when comparing (`if (*type == MyURLType2)`).

Answer (score 0):

why not define type as an int?  Then, you can compare the ints.  Simple and clean solution.

```
int type = MyURLTypeX;
```

will allow you to do

`if (type == MyURLType2)` since they're both ints.

How is it possible no one has suggested this yet?

Comment: Depending on your compiler settings, you might get a warning comparing int to MyURLType or int to NSInteger, so your proposal is bad in that situation.  In fact, if you haven't turned that warning on, I would recommend it.  You should always just say what you mean.  Declare it as `MyURLType type = MyURLTypeX;` and save confusing yourself later.  If you declare all enum values as ints then you're going end up comparing two entirely different enums one day and you'll spend ages figuring out what went wrong.

Answer (score -1):

was just researching this, but looks like another option is to cast the enum:

`if (type == (MyURLType *) MyURLType2)`